# Why is MSpec's ShouldBeOfType<T> assertion extension method missing?

Tags: mspec

I'm trying to use Mspec's `ShouldBeOfType<T>()` assertion extension method, but intellisense says that it can't find it. I'm using MSpec v0.7.0. I tried reinstalling using Nuget but didn't work.

```
[Subject("Prop Manager")]
public class When_Replying_To_Prop_Which_Already_Had_Emailed_And_No_Overwrite
{
    Because of = () => _exception = Catch.Exception(() => _PropManager.ReplyToProp());

    It should_result_in_an_error = () => _exception.ShouldBeOfType<InvalidOperationException>();

    private static Exception _exception;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of version 0.7.0, Machine.Specifications does not include assertions any more (see [Daniel Marbach's blog](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2014/02/12/machine-specifications-machine-specifications-should-0-7-0-released/)). You have to install [Machine.Specifications.Should](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Machine.Specifications.Should/0.7.0) (or another assertions library).

Additionally, `ShouldBeOfType()` has been replaced with `ShouldBeOfExactType()` (or `ShouldBeAssignableTo()` respectively), so you should also change that in your code (see [github issue](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/issues/171).

Comment: this breaking change has caught out a lot of people

Comment: Any idea why the assertions now exists in a separate library? Is it allow flexibility over what assertions library to use?

Comment: @Ciaran, for two reasons, I believe: flexibility to choose an assertions library and separation of concerns - while MSpec changes versions the assertions can remain stable and vice versa.